# DAX query to add numbers until a condition is met

Tags: dax

I have two columns named 'HA' and 'PA'. 
I want to add values in column 'HA' once it is greater than or equal to the value in 'PA'.

HA        PA

1.58       3.24

3.24       3.24

3.23       3.24

the values in column 'PA' will be the same. 
I want to add values in column 'HA' once the sum is greater than or equal to the value in column 'PA'
For eg:
it should add the first two rows (1.58 + 3.24 = 4.82) in column 'HA', as its sum will be greater than or equal to the value in columns 'PA'.
It should not add the 3rd value in column 'HA'.

Comment: you need to define order of the records. There are no row numbers in DAX.

Comment: question not clear